# Connection refused when trying to connect to local mysql database from docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, lumen, host

I have a problem to connect with local mysql database from a docker container. I'm using docker-compose with two services in containers, database is not on container

I have this docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
    web:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: web-dev.dockerfile
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        links:
            - app
        network_mode: "bridge"
        dns:
            - 10.0.50.6
    app:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: app-dev.dockerfile
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
        network_mode: "bridge"
        dns:
            - 10.0.50.6
```

the `web` container is an nginx service with this Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:1.10

ADD ./vhost.dev.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

WORKDIR /var/www
```

and this configuration file:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    index index.php index.html;
    root /var/www/formapp/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

the `app` container is an app service with this Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7-fpm

ENV USER=pasquale

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev mysql-client \
    openssl zip unzip git nano wget libaio-dev iputils-ping

RUN mkdir -p /opt/oracle/instantclient_10_2
# Download files from in oracle folder:
#   https://agora.zanichelli.it/downloads/basic-10.2.0.5.0-linux-x64.zip
#   https://agora.zanichelli.it/downloads/sdk-10.2.0.5.0-linux-x64.zip

ADD oracle/basic-10.2.0.5.0-linux-x64.zip /opt/oracle/basic-10.2.0.5.0-linux-x64.zip
ADD oracle/sdk-10.2.0.5.0-linux-x64.zip /opt/oracle/sdk-10.2.0.5.0-linux-x64.zip
RUN unzip /opt/oracle/basic-10.2.0.5.0-linux-x64.zip -d /opt/oracle \
    && unzip /opt/oracle/sdk-10.2.0.5.0-linux-x64.zip -d /opt/oracle \
    && ln -s /opt/oracle/instantclient_10_2/libclntsh.so.10.1 /opt/oracle/instantclient_10_2/libclntsh.so \
    && ln -s /opt/oracle/instantclient_10_2/libclntshcore.so.10.1 /opt/oracle/instantclient_10_2/libclntshcore.so \
    && ln -s /opt/oracle/instantclient_10_2/libocci.so.10.1 /opt/oracle/instantclient_10_2/libocci.so

ADD oracle/tns-admin/tnsnames.ora /opt/oracle/instantclient_10_2/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /opt/oracle/instantclient_10_2/

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    && pecl install mcrypt-1.0.1 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable mcrypt \
    && pecl install mongodb \
    && docker-php-ext-enable mongodb \
    && docker-php-ext-configure pdo_oci --with-pdo-oci=instantclient,/opt/oracle/instantclient_10_2,10.2 \
    && echo 'instantclient,/opt/oracle/instantclient_10_2' | pecl install oci8 \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_oci \
    && docker-php-ext-enable oci8

RUN yes | pecl install xdebug \
    && echo "zend_extension=$(find /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/ -name xdebug.so)" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo 'xdebug.remote_enable=1' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo 'xdebug.default_enable=1' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo 'xdebug.remote_connect_back=1' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo 'xdebug.remote_autostart=1' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo 'xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo 'xdebug.remote_port=9000' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo 'xdebug.remote_host=0.0.0.0' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo 'xdebug.remote_log=/var/www/xdebug.log' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini

RUN mkdir -p /home/$USER
RUN groupadd -g 1000 $USER
RUN useradd -u 1000 -g $USER $USER -d /home/$USER
RUN chown $USER:$USER /home/$USER
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

WORKDIR /var/www
USER $USER
```

launching the containers with `docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml up --build -d` works fine and `docker ps` command give me this output:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                           NAMES
7202e2862ef5        190todb_web         "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   9 hours ago         Up About an hour    443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp   190todb_web_1_3c628ae1c69b
d45c04d353d5        190todb_app         "docker-php-entrypoi…"   9 hours ago         Up About an hour    9000/tcp                        190todb_app_1_dd2ac7028b87
```

I install a lumen app in my project folder `formapp` and then I created a seeder to insert fake data in my database, and from bash, if I run `/projectfolder/formapp$ php artisan db:seed` the seeder works and I have this output:

```
Seeding: UsersTableSeeder
Database seeding completed successfully.
```

Then I created a route to access my users table from the lumen app:

```
$router->get('users', function () use ($router) {
    return User::all();
});
```

my lumen env file is this:

```
APP_NAME=Lumen
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost
APP_TIMEZONE=UTC

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL=

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=form_db
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=radiohead

CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync

JWT_SECRET=JhbGciOiJIUzI1N0eXAiOiJKV1QiLC
```

but if I try to connect from `http://localhost:8080/users` I have this lumen error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from `users`)
```

I tried to change the `DB_HOST` but I cannot solve the problem:

```
0.0.0.0 (SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from `users`));
172.17.0.1 (SQLSTATE[HY000] [1130] Host '172.17.0.2' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server (SQL: select * from `users`));
```

`172.17.0.1` is my docker0 inet address.

How can I config my project to work?

PS: the lumen app is up and running, is only the db connection that is not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `localhost` when the database and app are not on the same server.

You need to allow access by something like:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'172.17.0.2' IDENTIFIED BY '<password>';
```

You can replace `172.17.0.2` by wildcard `%`.

Comment: thanks, it works, but if I have to seed my db again I have to change my env `DB_HOST` again. Is there a way to manage this setup? I have to seed my db from inside the container?

Comment: @ufollettu you say the database server is not a docker container, so it won't change. Just put the correct hostname or IP address in `DB_HOST` and you are fine.

Comment: @ufollettu After setting the correct address, the host won't change, I don't understand what you mean by "seed the db again". Only do it once.

Comment: if I set `DB_HOST=172.17.0.1` and try `php artisan db:seed` I have an error `SQLSTATE[HY000] [1130] Host '10.0.38.77' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server` . Solved in the same way, I Grant the access to 'root'@'10.0.38.77' and all works. Thank you

Comment: @ufollettu aaah ok now I understand. I guess that's because there are internal and external IP addresses, especially in bridged networks. You can also use the wildcard `%` in the MySQL GRANT command but I suggest to use a good username and password then (not root).

Comment: Or use a hostname instead of the IP address (need to ensure proper resolving in the correct direction respectively).